# Adding online payment method in wordpress listing website

Tags: wordpress, seo, directory-listing

How I can add online payment method in wordpress theme for online listing website ?

I tried to add online payment method in my new listing website but did not get any solution so I am expecting solution to add this.

Waiting for reply.